# How can I make right mouse button click to shoot automatic and if clicking again the mouse left button it will shoot single each left mouse click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to toggle between left mouse button click for single shots and once one click on right mouse button will shoot automatic none stop until clicking the left mouse button again. And the automaticFire bool variable have no use since I'm talking about after building the game not in editor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool automaticFire = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool slowDownEffect = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
            {
                if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (/*automaticFire == true &&*/Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }

    bool isAnimationStatePlaying(Animator anim, int animLayer, string stateName)
    {
        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I tried :

```
if (/*automaticFire == true &&*/Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
```

But this will shoot single shots each time clicking the right mouse button.
And I want that one click on right mouse button will shoot automatic none stop and left click will switch to single shots.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

```
class Foo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializableField]
    private bool shooting = false;
    [SerializableField]
    private Animator anim;

    public void Update() 
    {
        if (shooting)
        {
            //if the shooting variable is set to true on the if below, it will start shooting
            anim.Play("Shooting");
            LaunchProjectile();
        }

        if (!shooting && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            anim.Play("Shooting");
            LaunchProjectile();
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            //reversing the shooting variable
            shooting = !shooting;
            if (shooting)
            {
                //this is just to make sure it will shoot right away
                //and not on the next frame
                anim.Play("Shooting");
                LaunchProjectile();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flag so when you click right mouse button then set a flag true, and play animation and Fire the projectile.

Changed code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool automaticFire = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool slowDownEffect = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
            {
                if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == true){
              automaticFire = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (/*automaticFire == true &&*/Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                {
                    automaticFire = true;
                }
                if (automaticFire == true )
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }

    bool isAnimationStatePlaying(Animator anim, int animLayer, string stateName)
    {
        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

if this helps consider an upvote and accepting the answer.

Comment: First I changed inside this checking the automaticFire to false either it's not working if it's true : else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == true)
            {
                automaticFire = false;
            } Second problem when it's on automatic fire I need to click the left mouse button many times until it's changing back to single shots. I think the problem is that I'm waiting for the animation to end on this line : if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true) and since that when it's on automatic the left mouse click not working all the time.

Comment: I have to catch it when the animation is not playing again.

Comment: The reason is that I'm waiting for the animation to end is that I want it to enable shooting only when aiming.